# how to decode json in perl if value has \n or more than one line

Tags: json, perl

how to decode the json file if a value has more than one line

a.json file:

```
{

            "sv1" : {
                  "output" : "Hostname: abcd
                              asdkfasfjsl",
                  "exp_result" : "xyz"
              }
}
```

when I try to read the above json file, I am hitting with an error "invalid character encountered while parsing JSON string, at character offset 50 (before "\n                  ...")"

code to read the above json file:

```
 #!/volume/perl/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use JSON;

 local $/;
 open(AA,"<a.json") or die "can't open json file : $!\n";
 my $json = <AA>;
 my $data = decode_json($json);
 print "reading output $data->{'sv1'}->{'output'}\n"; 
 print "reading output $data->{'sv1'}->{'exp_result'}\n";
 close AA;
```

Comment: Is it valid JSON in the first place? I'm not so sure it is.

Comment: Invalid json in a.json. See jsonlint.com

Comment: It is not valid JSON. Newline in JSON should be written with use of \n...

Comment: I got it. a.json is not valid file. i need to specify \n.

Answer (score 1):

Besides from whether the JSON is valid or not (see comments on question), you're reading only the first line from the file.

```
my $json = <AA>;
```

This is a scalar variable and receives only one line.

Use an array to get all lines:

```
my @json = <AA>;
my $json = join "\n", @json;
```

or even better: use [`File::Slurp::read_file`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_file) to get the whole content of the file with one simple command.

```
use File::Slurp qw/read_file/;
my $json = read_file( "a.json" );
```